# How to change the blur effect on parent window controls when childwindow shows

Tags: silverlight

Opening a ChildWindow will automatically apply a blur effect on parent window's textbox, textblock, etc. However, I don't need this effect. is there a way to change it.
I tried the OverlayOpacity and OverlayBrush, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I would direct you a previous question that I asked I think the answer I got would also answer your question [Leave parent window active when child opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584795/leave-parent-window-active-when-child-opens)